# Laravel 5.6 check and store multidimensional file array issue

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I can't get how to manage files in the controller if my file input is a multidimensional array. I'am stuck with this.

I.e. my html form:

```
<form>
   <!-- lots of stuff before images -->
   <input type="file" name="myImage[0][0]" />
   <input type="file" name="myImage[0][1]" />
   <input type="file" name="myImage[1][0]" />
   <!-- mode images -->
   <input type="file" name="myImage[5][3]" />
</form>
```

What the correct way would be for `request` variable in my controller to store those files?

In my case I already have preprocessed ids for request array, but seems it doesnt work with `file` type:

```
$form_item->title = $request->input('title')[$parent][$child]; // works fine

$form_item->image = $request->file('myImage')[$parent][$child]->store('images'); // Call to a member function store() on null

$form_item->save();
```

How to store file and apply hasFile validation in my case?

Comment: Shouldn't be `$request->file("myImage[$parent][$child]")` ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, thanks, but I've recently checked out and it doesn't work... I've also dumped request var, so `var_dump($request->input('form_item_image_file'))` returns `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "image.jpg" } }` but `var_dump($request->file('form_item_image_file'))` returns `NULL`. Strange..

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, so sorry, I forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to my form :( Thanks!